# What type of pen or pencil can I use to sign a print on satin paper

Tags: prints, limited-editions

I am having some prints done of some photographs for an art exhibition, the photos are mounted and framed, and the photo is printed so there is a small visible white border around the print before the mount of 7mm at left, right and top and 14mm at the bottom.

The intention is to number and sign the print at the bottom as is typically done with limited edition prints of paintings (and I believe photographs). But because they are printed on satin paper (Canson Baryta) a normal pencil will not work, and the pens I have tried are too black.

Is there a type of pencil or a pen which gives the apperance of being pencil that will work on this type of paper.

Comment: Have you considered signing the edge of the matte instead?

Comment: Yes but I really dont think its looks very good to sign the mount

Comment: Maybe ask Mike Johnston? :) See: http://theonlinephotographer.typepad.com/the_online_photographer/2014/05/pen-for-signing-prints.html, although hilariously, [Red River recommends](http://www.redrivercatalog.com/infocenter/tips/pens-pencils-for-signing-inkjet-prints.html) the Sakura Pigma that Micron Johnston didn't like.

Comment: What do you mean "too black"? You want it to give the impression it is a pencil line (as in graphite pencil)? So a grey line is the result you are expecting? Would you prefer alcohol-based, gel or pigment based (shinier when dry), paint-based?

Comment: Good links, yes I would like to give the impression of pencil or at least not have it to black so it doesnt distract from the image. I went into my local stationary and tried a whole host of pens and the best one I found was a Pilot G-TEC-C4 Black, this was nioce and fine, went on okay and disnt smudge but it was still too black. Apparently in their equivalent Japanese only range of Hi-Tec-C Gel Ink Pen they have Usuzumi (Light Sumi Gray) but when I ordered it on Amazon was cancelled as they had none in stock, not sure if it still made in this colour.

Comment: @fabriced I've now ordered a range of grey ink pens from cultpens to see if any of them work. I have no idea of the advantages of alcohol-based, gel or pigment based (shinier when dry), paint-based ?

Comment: I have a passion for the best pencil ever (re)made. Have a peek at any of the 3 different Blackwing™ (Half the pressure, twice the speed.) Palomino pencils. There are the "standard," the "602," and the "Pearl." They are expensive, though. Use a good quality sharpener such as a mascara sharpener or the Blackwing™ one.

Comment: @Stan but its still a pencil, are you saying it will actually work on Canson Baryta paper ?

Comment: My definition of "works" might be different from yours. Go to an art supply store with some paper samples to try it/them on.

Comment: @Stan, I think the important think to look for, whether alcohol, gel, or pigment, is whether the ink/pigment is _archival_. (See [how Sharpies aren't](https://shellielewis.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/sharpie-markers/)).

Comment: @iskista - rocks (graphite) in a pencil are pretty stable. ; ) India ink contains carbon particles suspended with a varnish in water. This is the best AFAIK. Alcohol is the vehicle in a marker to dissolve and transport the colorant (usually a dye such as aniline (organic, moderately stable), plant (organic, unstable), or other colorant. Some roller markers have metal colorants which are stable beyond the fibres of the paper it's on. Stability is usually expressed as a three-letter designation. The most stable designation is AAA, the next is AAB, ABB, etc.

Comment: @Stan certainly with a normal pencil its clear that it doesnt work no argument. But is there something special about these pencils allowing them to work on photo paper or are you simply advertising that you like a particular pencil?

Comment: So I ordered some pens and found that the Kuretake Zig Mangaka Pen 02 Grey worked very well. Its a fine tip and the grey is considerably lighter than all the other pens I tried, however I have no idea about ink stabililtybut their website http://www.kuretake.co.uk/products/education/mangaka.aspx says it is Lightfast Pigment Ink thats sounds promising.

Comment: I am responding to your request for a "pencil" in the post. One experiment is worth 1000 expert opinions. – Bill Nye, The science guy. As I mentioned in a previous comment, there are various degrees of "lightfast" pigments. Some are more stable than others. Carbon (stone) and graphite (stone) is pretty lightfast (AAA). The "satin" finish is a texture on the paper whose "hills" and "valleys" will somewhat soften the otherwise regular "density" of the stroke. As far as the required tooth of a surface, Palomino will make a nice line on the glossiest stock I could find in my studio. TRY it my man.

Answer (score 1):

I routinely print on Canson Baryta paper.  I leave a white border around the image and sign with a Pigma Micron archival ink pen.  It is black, but the do have other colors.